# Using javascriptexecutor to change the css background value in selenium

Tags: javascript, css, selenium

This is my code:

```
String color = "#ff0000";
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphContentBody_ctl01_loginControl_LoginButton"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border = '3px solid red'", login);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = '" + color + "'" , login);
```

I am able to change the border but unable to change the backgroundColor and I am not getting any error too.

PS: I don't know much javascript.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [backgroundColor](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp) *Property*, to set the background color for a document, the line of code is:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

So, to to change the backgroundColor you need to:

```
String color = "red";
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphContentBody_ctl01_loginControl_LoginButton"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border = '3px solid red'", login);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = '" + color + "'" , login);
```